# How to solve this type of error when firing ionic cordova resources Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting this error when I am firing ionic cordova resources Android

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket.`_finishInit` (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/self-sign-certificate-error-after-ionic-ionic-start/90101

As a summary there are two possible solutions provided:

1) Gratefully found one temporary solution, but of course, TEMPORARY.
"if this is a self signed cert issue then you can temporarily set an environment variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 then clear the variable when you are done"
REF: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2317

2) It basically comes down to adding the proxy property to your ionic.config.json file (located in the root of your project). This overcomes both the Self-Signed Certificate issue and (if applicable) CORS.

```
{
  ...
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "proxyUrl": "<url-to-your-domain> e.g. https://api.ionicrun:8443/",
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  ]
}
```